# Android/java multi threaded fetch and store images in arraylist in order

Tags: android, multithreading, image, arraylist

I needed to fetch a series of images in sequence.
Atm I have a thread fetching these images in sequence and store them in an array list in a separate thread.

And another thread is used to read and display the images from the arraylist. If the "playback" is in advance, it sleeps for 3 seconds (buffering) waiting for the arraylist to fill up.

It works relatively well but there is too much buffering.

The issue is that the arraylist does not fill up fast enough.

I think i need to do multiple fetching of the images and the problem is how to manage the order in the arraylist and how to make sure there are no "holes" in the arraylist? (Frame 2 loaded before frame 1)

Comment: What about filter downloaded images when display. After new images downloaded, refresh UI.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean

Comment: Ok I got it. I use a ThreadPoolExecutor for multi threaded downloading of images and a hashmap to preserve order

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got it. I use a ThreadPoolExecutor for multi threaded downloading of images and a hashmap to preserve the order